# PHPstorm 8 unable to authenticate subversion (1.8)

Tags: svn, authentication, phpstorm

I've problem with `PHPStorm 8` with subversion.

I want to login in to my Subversion server and checkout a project. But PHPStorm does not authenticate with the correct login credits. But when i use Netbeans 8, it works. In Netbeans 8 i have selected SvnKit als client.

**Error:**

```
2014-10-13 12:02:22,159 [ 306960]   WARN - svn.auth.AuthenticationService - Could not get authentication. Type - svn.simple, Url - http:// [ip] /svn/projects 

2014-10-13 12:02:37,641 [ 322442]   WARN - svn.auth.AuthenticationService - Could not get authentication. Type - svn.simple, Url - svn+ssh:// [ip] /var/svn-repos/projects 

OS: Apple Mac OSX 10.9.5 

Svn: 1.8.8 
PHPStorm: 8.0.1 
Netbeans: 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
```